# Can a bounty be awarded to an answer in a comment?

Tags: support, comments, bounty

Recently I have placed a bounty on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137383/sieve-bound-for-prime-k-tuples).
The question has no answer in technical terms, but it has been answered
in a comment within the bounty period.
Now the banner below the question says that the question had a bounty from me which ended
so-and-so many minutes ago, and it says also "you have 23 hours to award the bounty".
-- Can I actually do this?

Comment: You could ask them to turn their comment into an answer so that you can award them the bounty.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Thanks. -- I have done so. Let's see whether the answerer gets back to it before MO runs out of patience ... .

Comment: I would have thought the grace period applies to the awarder of the bounty, not to potential answerers. That is, is it actually possible to award the bounty to an answer posted after the bounty has ended?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Yes.  Here is a meta.stackoverflow.com question about that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134943/are-answers-posted-during-the-grace-period-eligible-for-bounties

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

The best you can do is what you just did after Michael's suggestion: comment to ask the user to post it as an answer if you would like to award the bounty.